# How to count words that end with a letter? (python)

Tags: python, split

I am a beginner and this is what I came up with so far. However, it does not output the correct number of words that end with "a" or "b." Any tips on how to correct this code?

```
names = input("Enter list of names: ")

name = names.split(" ")

num = len(name)

ab = ""

print("Number of words:", num)

for i in range(num):
    if name[i] == ' ':
        if name[i-1] == a:
            ab.append() + " "
        elif name[i-1] == b:
            ab.append() + " "

a_b = ab.split(' ')        

print("Number of words that end with a or b: ",len(a_b))
```

Comment: `name[i-1]` is not the last character. It's the previous name in the list. I think you mean `name[i][-1]`

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: Maybe consider [`str.endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith)

Comment: @Mark today I learned `str.endswith()` accepts tuples of things to match for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python boolean (`True` and `False`) are the same as the integers `1` and `0`. This means you can use `sum()` to count `True` booleans. `str.endswith()` returns a boolean. This means you can just do this:

```
words = ["stab", "drama", "hello", "magma", "test"]

a_b = sum(word.endswith(('a', 'b')) for word in words) 
# 3

z_c = sum(word.endswith(('z', 'c')) for word in words) 
# 0
```

Answer (score 2):

> Any tips on how to correct this code?

Others have answered alternative, working solutions, but I want to try to point  out the specific things wrong in your code snippet and tips to correct.

First here's a copy of your snippet with some simple debugging prints along with their output (running in python 3.10).

```py
names = "Barry Lima Bab"

name = names.split(" ")
print(f"{name=}")  # name=['Barry', 'Lima', 'Bab']

num = len(name)
print(f"{num=}")  # num=3

ab = ""

print("Number of words:", num)

for i in range(num):
    print(name[i])  # Barry -> Lima -> Bab
    if name[i] == ' ':
        if name[i-1] == a:
            ab.append() + " "
        elif name[i-1] == b:
            ab.append() + " "

print(f"{ab=}")  # ab=''
a_b = ab.split(' ')
print(f"{a_b=}")  # a_b=['']
```

Breaking things down step by step like this is a great starting point for better understanding what's going on.

1. `if name[i] == ' ':` Notice the value of `name[i]` so this check never resolves to True meaning the code inside never runs
2. if the inner code *did* run, you'd hit a `NameError: name 'a' is not defined. Did you mean: 'ab'?` because `a` is undefined. Probably meant `'a'` here. same for `b`
3. In my example, `name[i-1]` would be `'Bab' -> 'Barry' -> 'Lima'` which is probably not what you're expecting. This is because you're getting the -1th, 0th, 1st items in `name`. to get the last letter from the name, you want `name[i][-1]` here
4. if you then get into either of the furthest inside conditions, you'd encounter `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'` which happens because `append` is for `list` not `str`. You couldchange `ab` to be a list to use this in which case you'd want `ab.append(name[i])` or you can use string concatenation like `ab += " " + name[i]` or using `str.concat`
5. 1 last note of interest, you may have noticed your code as-is really likes to return and say that there's 1 item. This is because the above issues always (if the program doesn't break) leaves `ab == ''` and `''.split(' ') => ['']` and thus `len(ab.split(" ")) => 1`

1 tip that I think would help in code comprehension is that the `name` variable here is *not* a single name string like it implies. It's actually a `list[str]`. I'd probably denote the variables something more like `names_str: str` vs `names: list[str]` or `raw_names` vs `names`. Then just use something like `for name in names:` and not worry about indexes. You can also use `name.endswith('a')` instead of `name[-1] == 'a'` for better readability.

Eventually you can combine these into a list comprehension for maximal succinctness -> `len([name for name in names if name.endswith('a') or name.endswith('b')])`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
words = ["ab", "bab", "pa", "pap"]

result = 0
for word in words:
    if word[-1] in "ab":
        result += 1

print(result)
```

Comment: Good call, thanks @JackDeeth

Answer (score 0):

As a list comprehension:

```
words = ["word1a", "word2b", "word3", "word4", "word5a"]  # ['word1a', 'word2b', 'word5a']
filtered_words = [word for word in words if word[-1] in "ab"]
filtered_words = [word for word in words if word.endswith(("a", "b"))]  # better, if you have multiple endings you want to search for with different lengths
len(filtered_words)  # 3
```

Answer (score 0):

`name[i-1]` is the previous name in the list, not the last character of the current name in the loop.

There's no need to append the matching names to a string. If you just need the count of matches, increment a counter variable.

You need to put `a` and `b` in quotes to make them strings, not variables.

```
names = input("Enter list of names: ")
name = names.split(" ")

matches = 0

print("Number of words:", len(name))

for cur_name in name:
    if cur_name.endswith('a') or cur_name.endswith('b'):
        matches += 1
    
print("Number of words that end with a or b: ", matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `endswith` string method to detect if the last letter is "a" or "b"

```
names = ["bob","boba","larry","curly","moe"]
count = 0
for name in names:
    if name.endswith("a") or name.endswith("b"):
        count += 1
print(f"{count=}") # count=2
```